# How to download search results from Google custom search?

Tags: javascript, python, search-engine, html

There are websites with google custom search. But when the search results are out, I am unable to save these results in the native html.

For e.g. I want to search for `(ITE)` on this website http://www.asiaone.com/A1Home/A1Home.html
The result page is:

http://www.asiaone.com/vgn-ext-templating/asiaone/search/A1MultipleSearchResults.jsp?q=%28ITE%29&cx=009076860783986227266%3Atwgr1shu6je

but when i tried to download the source of that result page, the results and the synopsis is not available on the flat HTML.

**Is there any library available in python or any other software that can download these synopsis from the search results?** I have something like this but the html source doesnt have the synopsis nor the search results:

```
import urllib
url = "http://www.asiaone.com/vgn-ext-templating/asiaone/search/A1MultipleSearchResults.jsp?q=%28" + "ITE" + "%29&cx=009076860783986227266%3Atwgr1shu6je"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read().decode('UTF-8')
print html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to access: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=&cx=009076860783986227266:Atwgr1shu6je&q=ITE

I am entering my own key that I got from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=customsearch.

But, I get invalid value error as my key is not associated with your cx id. 
You have to put your key here and get the results.

PS: Dont enter your key here in the comments or the question. It can cost you money (https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=customsearch:billing)

You can refer to https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#WorkingResults. It is clearly mentioned what you need to do to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [Google XML API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results) - It should have the functionality you're looking for.

If you're hellbent on getting the python equivalent, have a look at Google's [Data API clients](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/client-libraries?hl=da) - they contain tools and examples to help you build your own apps with integrated google data.